# Is a local equation for a smooth point on a curve given by the equation for the "tangent line"?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an algebraic curve in $A^m$ defined by some equations $F = (f_1, \ldots, f_n)$. If $p$ on $X$ is a smooth point, general nonsense guarantees that there is a local equation for $p$. Is this equation given by the equations for the tangent line, i.e. the Jacobian of $F$ at $p$?

Comment: Yes, just expand in a finite Taylor series around the point.

Comment: @user40276 Can you expand on your answer a little?

Comment: Look at page 147 and 148 of Wedhorn and Gortz "Algebraic Geometry 1", if you don't understand something, I can clarify it.

Comment: @user40276 Unfortunately I don't have access to that book.

Comment: @AreaMan Google "gortz wedhorn" and see what you find.

Comment: First of all, I assume that the two $n$'s appearing in your question are not the same. Secondly, what exactly do you mean by a local equation for $p$?

Comment: @user40276 I read the pages - I'm not asking about an equation for tangent plane, but for the point p. (Local equation of a subvariety.) I don't see the connection, but the book is certainly nice.

Comment: @Mohan Yes, the ns are distinct. A mean a generator for the maximal ideal in the local ring at x, or (I think) equivalently, a function regular in some neighborhood that cuts out x (in that nbhd).

Comment: Oh, now I understand your question. The uniformizer of the valuation ring is the generator of the tangent space after quotienting by the square of the maximal ideal.

Comment: However the equation around the point can have second order derivatives, while the tangent line not. So the answer is no

Comment: I'm still confused. In general there isn't "an equation" for something of higher codimension. What, for example, is the "local equation" for the z-axis in A^3?

Comment: @JohnBrevik I think the OP means a generator of the maximal ideal of the local ring at the point $p$.

Comment: (I think in general it is something that can be asked about codimension 1 subvarieties...)

Comment: @user40276 What do you mean by the equation having second order derivatives? The local equation? But it isn't unique, isn't it? I'm still confused. Can you give an example where the equation of the tangent line won't cut out the point $p$ locally? (I mean, the tangent line is going to intersect the curve at finitely many points, so there is a neighborhood where it cuts out that point. Is there something wrong with multiplicity?)

Comment: The local equation is  unique up to a unit. When you localize at $p$ (that is you localize at $(x_1 - p_1, …, x_n - p_n)$), each $f_i$ has an expansion in Taylor series (around $(p_1, …, p_n)$) and these expansions generates the maximal ideal. When you quotient again by the maximal ideal ($\mathfrak{m}_p/\mathfrak{m}_p^2$) each term of order two in the taylor expansion vanishes.

Comment: If you looked at the case of plane curves, you would already see that the tangent line (since it meets the curve at least twice at $p$) can never be a local equation.

Comment: @Mohan Oh ... Now I see the problem with looking at the world with non-schemey eyes.

Comment: @Mohan So how do I find local equations? For instance if I want to compute the divisor of some rational function, I need the local equation to compute the valuation...

Comment: Use the equation for the `normal' hyperplane (so, quite different from the tangent line).

Comment: @Mohan Makes sense, thanks.

Comment: @Mohan So, a local equation would be any curve that intersects with multiplicity one? Does this mean I can bypass the local equation > valuation computation, and simply compute the intersection multiplcity of the hypersurface defined by my function and the curve at the point p? This is done by computing the k dimension of the tensor product over the affine coordinate ring?

Comment: @Mohan For the second sentance, I forgot to say that I want to compute the divisor associated to a regular function by computing intersection multiplicities.

Comment: If you look at intersection multiplicity this gives the order of vanishing at the point.

Comment: @Mohan which is 1 iff it gives a local equation?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.